# Cookies conflict in domain - subdomain

Tags: php, cookies

We have a website *www.example.com* that use some cookies.
And we have a copy of this website in a subfolder like these:

```
www.example.com:8000/test/
```

The copy of this subfolder is for testing.

We create the cookies like this (for example) in the domain and in the subfolder:

```
setcookie("name", "value", time() + 1800);
```

And when we navigate into domain and subfolder on different tabs into the same navigator we have conflict between cookies because we have the same cookies in both.

I think that we can do this in the subfolder:

```
setcookie("name", "value", time() + 1800, "test", "www.example.com:8000");
```

To my knowledge this creates only the cookies in the subfolder and one part of the problem would be solved. 
But, to my knowledge, when we create a cookie in the root of the domain, this cookie is also available in the subfolders... then the problem will continue...

Anyone knows how can I define a cookie only for the root folder of the domain?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't**

Cookies are strongly connected with website. A domain to be specific. And that's why they are great and powerfull. Any cookie defined **anywhere** within `www.example.com` will be accessible in any page on this domain. But on the `www.blog.example.com` however, that cookie will not be accessible, as subdomains are technically separate domains/websites. Folders and subdirectiories are not.

Using subfolder allows you to set cookie to more deep parts of website. But you cannot limit cookie to root only.

**How to help you**

Use different names for your cookies.

Comment: Changing the name of the cookie! definitely the easiest solution. Was having a conflict on subdomain: .example.com and .sub.example.com, the latter picking up the cookie from former.